# Accessing a variable whose value is set in an AJAX function

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, methods, global-variables

I've got a problem. I've been trying to solve the problem of how to avoid using global variables. I decided to use an object with functions on it instead, and wrote a script accordingly. However, the script won't run as expected:

```
GetXML: function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "questions.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                this.xml=xml;
                $(window).trigger("canUseXML");
                var docLength = $(xml).find('Question').length + 1;
                alert("this really is an '" + this.xml + "' and the actual doclength is: " + docLength)//This is the first alert I mention.         
            } //close success           
        });//close AJAX     

        alert("yes! this is still a: " +this.xml) //This is the second alert I mention.
    },
```

If it all ran as expected, both alerts would result in an 'object XMLDocument' (a variable declared elsewhere in this line: `this.xml = null;`). The first runs as expected. However, the second, outside of that function, returns value "null". Why?

Thanks, Elliot Bonneville

P.S. I've been stuck on the seemingly simple question of passing variables between functions for a week.

Comment: Please tag this with whatever language it is that you are using

Comment: What's the language?  You should put it into the tags to make it clear.

Comment: Also, titles like "A simple logical error" (e.g. "I have an error", "Here's a problem", "Please fix my code", etc.) doesn't really contribute to SO's future users scanning titles for relevant articles.  I respectfully suggest using a more descriptive title (e.g. "Accessing a variable whose value is set in an AJAX function")

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the polite way you put it. Following advice.

Comment: Is the problem simply that the 2nd alert is accessing `this.xml` before the AJAX call is completed and the `this.xml` is set? Since AJAX is *asynchronous*, it seems the 2nd alert needs to be deferred until the call is determined to be completed.

Comment: I don't think so, because I work with this variable later in the code in a function that is called only after success is called; this variable also seems to have the same problem.

Comment: @Eliot - Thanks for being so open and responsive to the suggestions.

Comment: Of course - I only hurt myself if I refuse to cooperate. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript "this" always refers to the “owner” of the function executed, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of. So your first and second "this" does not refer to the same thing.

Assuming that the "success" function executes before the second alert (which it probably doesn't). You could do something like this:

```
GetXML: function() {
 var that=this;
.
.
```

and then use "that" instead of "this".

Comment: When I declare "that", I get "missing : after property id" in Firebug and my alerts don't function. Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Scoping. 
Once you travel outside of anonymous function(xml) this.xml no longer exists.

Comment: No, because like I said earlier, this variable is declared earlier in the code. Scoping problems are what this object and its methods are designed to prevent.

Comment: Yes and no: `this.xml` does exist, but `this` inside the anonymous function is different from `this` outside of it.

Comment: it doesn't matter if you declare it earlier. this inside the function and this outside the function are different.

Comment: Really? That explains a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. Scoping: `this` inside the callback is not your object with `GetXML` as a member. Use something like `me = this;` in the constructor of your object and then use `me` instead of `this` to explicitely set the value.
2. You callback function waits for a success of your Ajax request, but the rest of the script is going on, which is the purpose of callbacks. So, the Ajax request is made, and then you do `alert("yes! this is still a: " +this.xml)`, while the callback has not yet been executed.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because ajax takes time to process. Javascript doesn't wait for one request before executing the next command, so while AJAX is being called, its trying to figure out what happened to this.xml.

Comment: If you're going to down vote my answer, please state the reason.